# Json objects not parsing with double quotes

Tags: json, gson

If I use single quotes its working fine, but not with double quotes.Can any one pls let me know what's missing in my code?

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonValue = "[{“name”: “Kadam”, “active”: true}]";
DeliveryGroup[] data = gson.fromJson(jsonValue.toString(), DeliveryGroup[].class);
for (DeliveryGroup hello: data) {
    System.out.println(hello.getName() + " : " + hello.getActive());
}
```

null : null

Comment: Typographic quotes ("curly quotes") don't work in JSON. If I had to guess, I would say you have copypasted this piece of code at least partly from a blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape special characters inside the string.

Try this,

```
String jsonValue="[{\"name\": \"Kadam\", \"active\": true}]";
```

Comment: Your answer does not contain typographic quotes as specified in the question.

Comment: It's same thing you have to do for any special charactor. I thought it's a mistake in question, because we normally dont use typographic quotes in JSON objects

Answer (score 0):

Json only supports straight quotes `" "`, here you are using opening and closing quotes `“ ”`.

You need first to correct your data as such:

```
[{"name": "Kadam", "active": true}]
```

And then quote it properly for your language:

```
String jsonValue='[{"name": "Kadam", "active": true}]';
#or
String jsonValue="[{\"name\": \"Kadam\", \"active\": true}]";
```